# Find out the members of Subgroup using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Administrators Group on my system. It contains some members .
I can easily find out all members of Administrator Group .But i want to find all members of a subgroup of Administrators using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (gp != null) // gp is your instance of GroupPrincipal 
{
  foreach (Principal p in gp .GetMembers(recursive: true))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
  }
  gp .Dispose();
}
```